# how to store image path in mysql database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

i am developing windows form to save an image path in database and then to retrieve that image using its path stored in database. My code saves the path but the slashes "/" are excluded. so help me how to save the image path correctly. Here is my code.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imagePath = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
                label23.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.ToString();
                Image thumbnail = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName).GetThumbnailImage(214, 186, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
                pictureBox1.Image = thumbnail;
                command.CommandText = "insert into student values ('imagePaht')";
                con.Open();
                command.Connection = con;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I think `imagePaht` is a local variable. What is the value of it exactly? And you need the double quote (`"`) at the end of your `CommandText` line.

Comment: imagePath is global variable and sorry i had forgotten the quotes in the question but my query runs and it save the entry but it does not save the slashes ("/"). Slashes are excluded in the database that's why it doesn't read the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` so the slashes are not removed. Another route is to double them, but that's not a good way.

```
command.CommandText = @"insert into student values ('imagePaht')";
```